# Warning: Illegal string offset 'custom_css_post_id'

Tags: php, wordpress

Please help me with this error. I am new to coding, I have a wordpress site and it shows the following error

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'custom_css_post_id' in /home/content/n3pnexwpnas02_data02/18/3031418/html/wp-includes/theme.php on line 905

Where should I start. Can someone help me since I am a noob.

Here is the code it points to in theme.php

```
function wp_get_custom_css_post( $stylesheet = '' ) {
if ( empty( $stylesheet ) ) {
    $stylesheet = get_stylesheet();
}

$custom_css_query_vars = array(
    'post_type'              => 'custom_css',
    'post_status'            => get_post_stati(),
    'name'                   => sanitize_title( $stylesheet ),
    'posts_per_page'         => 1,
    'no_found_rows'          => true,
    'cache_results'          => true,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false,
    'update_term_meta_cache' => false,
);

$post = null;
if ( get_stylesheet() === $stylesheet ) {
    $post_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_css_post_id' );

    if ( $post_id > 0 && get_post( $post_id ) ) {
        $post = get_post( $post_id );
    } else {
        $query = new WP_Query( $custom_css_query_vars );
        $post = $query->post;
        /*
         * Cache the lookup. See WP_Customize_Custom_CSS_Setting::update().
         * @todo This should get cleared if a custom_css post is added/removed.
         */
        if ( $post ) {
            set_theme_mod( 'custom_css_post_id', $post->ID );
        } elseif ( -1 !== $post_id ) {
            set_theme_mod( 'custom_css_post_id', -1 );
        }
    }
} else {
    $query = new WP_Query( $custom_css_query_vars );
    $post = $query->post;
}

return $post;
```

}

Comment: Where do you get the error? What are you trying to do when you receive it?

Comment: This means you've used a string where you're supposed to be using an associative array.

Comment: At the top of the page I get the error, the main navigation menu in my site is messed up. Where should find line 905 to locate the code?

Comment: Please someone help me?

Comment: Why is no one helping me?

Answer (score 1):

How I resolved this issue

1. switch to another default theme (I used twenty nineteen) and re-assign a primary menu.
2. jump into the db and search in the options for 'theme_mods_' there should be one for each theme in there. One is your broken theme and you should fine the other one twentynineteen.
3. copy the options value from twenty nineteen and set it for the value for your broken theme. Then switch it back and assign the primary menu again.

It might not be the best solution but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, and found something on this link:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/illegal-string-offset-warning-4/

I didn't get anything from this.  but may be you can undesrstand something from this.

and please reply back if you found something usefull. :)

Thanks.

It looks like a un-necessary WordPress warning being shown on lots of websites these days, and never any question posted on it before.

So I used a trick to stop the wordpress showing these issues on production server.

but you can remove this trick on your development server.  have a look:

just put this below code after

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

in wp-config.php

```
ini_set('log_errors','On');
ini_set('display_errors','Off');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```